# How to use Transaction in two Tables in Same Time?

Tags: hibernate, transactions

How to use Hibernate Transaction in with different tables but in the same time?

Answer (score 0):

You start a transaction, do everything you want with as many entities as you want, then commit the transaction, as shown in [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#transactions-demarcation-nonmanaged)

```
// Non-managed environment idiom with getCurrentSession()
try {
    factory.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();

    // do some work
    ...

    factory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
}
catch (RuntimeException e) {
    factory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().rollback();
    throw e; // or display error message
}
```

Comment: Got you, but my doubt is with in the transaction can we use more than 1 Session object ?  i think different table means different object means different session, if i am correct.

Comment: No, you're not correct. Read [this part of the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#architecture-overview-terms), then read the rest of it.